# unknown type name

Tags: c

Estoy creando un TDA en el que uso estructuras de otros TDA para llamadas a funciones, y aunque tengo incluidos los .h de dichos TDA en el .c, cuando escribo dichas funciones en el .h me sale el error "unknown type name" para las estructuras Imagen y Bala

```
#include "Ejercito.h"
#include "rafaga.h"
#include "Pantalla.h"
#include "Colisiones.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct EnemigoRep{
double x;
double y;
double w;
double h;};

struct EjercitoRep{
Enemigo datos[10];
int tope;};

void dibuja_ejercito(Ejercito e,Imagen ImEnemigo){
if(e->tope==-1){
    return;
};
for(int i=0;i<e->tope;i=i+1){
    Pantalla_DibujaImagen(ImEnemigo,e->datos[i]->x,e->datos[i]->y,e->datos[i]->w,e->datos[i]->h);
};};

int colision_ejercito_rafaga(Ejercito e,rafaga r){
int n=0;
for(int i=0;i<e->tope;i=i+1){
    if(colision_rafaga(r,e->datos[i]->x,e->datos[i]->y,e->datos[i]->w,e->datos[i]->h)){
        Enemigo s=e->datos[i];
        for(int d=i;d<e->tope;d=d+1){
            e->datos[d]=e->datos[d+1];
        };
        e->tope=-1;
        free(s);
        n=n+1;
    };
};
return n;};
```

Esto en el .c y en el .h :

```
#ifndef __EJERCITO_H__
#define __EJERCITO_H__

typedef struct EnemigoRep * Enemigo;
typedef struct EjercitoRep * Ejercito;

void dibuja_ejercito(Ejercito e,Imagen ImEnemigo);
int colision_ejercito_rafaga(Ejercito e,rafaga r);
#endif // __EJERCITO_H__
```

No entiendo porque me sale dicho error ya que en rafaga.h también uso estructuras de otros TDA (uno de ellos también Imagen) y ahí no me da error. También, se supone que tengo añadidos los correspondientes TDA al .c de Ejercito.h, por eso no entiendo porque me sale dicho error, ya que en el .c no me aparece y me compila sin ningún problema.

Y el problema no es que no use los nombres correctos... Ya que en sus respectivos TDA están definidos así en el .h:

```
typedef struct Nodo * rafaga;

typedef struct ImagenRep *Imagen;
```

Comment: Siendo que el .h es lo primero que mira tu compilador, cuando estas haciendo el typedef como
se supone que el compilador sabe lo que `EnemigoRep` y `EjercitoRep` es?